# Assertion failed: (forceBreakIndex > NSMaxRange(lastResortNode->lineBreak.range)), function -[_NSOptimalLineBreaker _calculateOptimalWrapping]

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nsattributedstring

I found a bug which is to parse an HTML string with `NSAttributedString` and use it in a `UITextView` using `AttributedText`. The error is this:

> Assertion failed:
> (forceBreakIndex > NSMaxRange(lastResortNode->lineBreak.range)), function -[_NSOptimalLineBreaker _calculateOptimalWrapping], file NSOptimalLineBreaker.m, line 1706.

The parsing seems to be working fine on iOS 15 or below. But in iOS 16 or above, it's crashing with the error mentioned above.

Any workaround for this, or is it just a problem because of the iOS version?

I have tried using the parsing with the most simple `NSAttributedString` for the HTML content, but it's still crashing for iOS 16 or above.

So for my parsing code of HTML content, i'm using this:

```
func setHTMLContent(_ htmlContent: String, font: UIFont, textColor: UIColor) {
    guard let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlContent.data(using: .utf8)!, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) else { return }
        
    attributedString.addAttributes([.font: font, .foregroundColor: textColor], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
        self.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

And to use this for some textview just simply called:

```
SomeTextView.setHTMLContent("Some HTML content", font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), textColor: .white)
```

For some HTML it worked flawlessly on iOS 16 above. But for another HTML it crashes on iOS 16 above. But it worked just fine on iOS 16 below. I can't provide the HTML content that makes this crashed because it's confidential. Why i think the problem is not in the HTML content is because for example on iOS 15 it worked just fine, so i think it would be something about using `NSAttributedString` parsing on iOS 16 that caused the crash.

Comment: It will be hard to confirm it is a bug if you can not provide the code/content that produces the crash. I suggest you try to iterate over your "confidential content" to find out what makes it crash.

Answer (score 1):

If html string contains `&nbsp;` in the middle of sentence then this issue is happening.
Before converting html to attributed string, just replace the `&nbsp;` to the space and then convert it.
I hope this answer help you.

Comment: I used your solution, and it worked like a charm for the html that causes the crashed. Thankyou very much!

Comment: In my case, the non-breaking space characters were in the format `&#160;` but the solution was the same -- replace any non-breaking space characters with a regular space character, and the issue goes away. Thank you!